# ReactJS - pass object keys and values as props to div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In my Class component `Field.jsx` `render()`, I'm expanding my `<Position>` component using `<Flipper>`, (an abstracted flip animation), like so:

```
import { Flipper, Flipped } from 'react-flip-toolkit'
import { Position } from "./Position";
import "./css/Position.css";

class Field extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fullScreen: false,
    };
  }

toggleFullScreen() {
    this.setState({ fullScreen: !this.state.fullScreen });
  }
...

render() {
    const { players } = this.props;
    const { fullScreen } = this.state;
    if(players){
      return (
       <div className="back">
         
          <div className="field-wrapper" >
            <Output output={this.props.strategy} />

            <Flipper flipKey={fullScreen}>
              <Flipped flipId="player">

                <div className="field-row"> 
                   {this.getPlayersByPosition(players, 5).map((player,i) => (
                      <Position
                        key={i} 
                        className={fullScreen ? "full-screen-player" : "player"}
                        getPositionData={this.getPositionData}
                        toggleFullScreen={this.toggleFullScreen.bind(this)}
                      >{player.name}</Position>
                    ))} 
                </div>

              </Flipped>
            </Flipper>

          </div>
        </div>
      );

  }else{
    return null}
  }
```

---

When I render it, I get clickable items from the mapped function `getPlayersByPosition()`, like so:

[image]

---

And if I click on each item, it expands to a div with player name:

[image]

Which is passed as props.children at component `<div>`

---

`Position.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import "./css/Position.css";


export const Position = props => (
  <div
    className={props.className}
    onClick={() => {
        props.getPositionData(props.children);
        props.toggleFullScreen();
        console.log(props.getPositionData(props.children))
    }}
  >
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

---

`getPositionData()`, however, returns an object with many items on its turn, as seen by console above:

```
{matches: 7, mean: 6.15, price: 9.46, value: 0.67, G: 3, …}
```

---

**QUESTION**:

**How do I pass and print theses other props keys and values on the expanded purple `div` as text?, so as to end with**:

```
Patrick de Paula
matches: 7
mean: 6.15
price:9.46
....
```

---

NOTE:

`Position.css`

```
.position-wrapper {
  height: 4em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #888888;
  flex: 1;
  /*outline: 1px solid #888888;*/
}


.player {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  /*background-color: #66CD00;*/
  color: #ffffff;
}

.full-screen-player {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgb(121, 113, 234),
    rgb(97, 71, 182)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the props are all set & ready to be print as seen on your console. You can access them via `props.getPositionData(props.children).property_name_here` or destructure them

```
export const Position = props => {

    const { matches, mean, price } = props.getPositionData(props.children);

    return (
        <div
            className={props.className}
            onClick={() => {
                props.getPositionData(props.children);
                props.toggleFullScreen();
                console.log(props.getPositionData(props.children))
            }}
        >
            <p>Name: {props.children}</p>
            <p>Matches: {matches}</p>
            <p>Mean: {mean}</p>
            <p>Price: {price}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Regarding the issue on the `fullScreen` prop (see comments section):

> Is there a way to print them ONLY after toggleFullScreen()

Since you already have a state on the `Field` component which holds your `fullScreen` value, on your `Field` component, you need to pass the `fullScreen` prop as well to the `Position` component. e.g., `fullScreen={this.state.fullScreen}`. Back on `Position` component, have some condition statements when you are rendering.

Example:

```
<>
  {props.fullScreen && 
    <p>Name: {props.children}</p>
  }
</>
```

Comment: thanks, looks about right! when I add `const {matches, mean, price} = props.getPositionData(props.children);`, I get  `Line 7:2:  Parsing error: Unexpected token`. what is wrong?

Comment: You can’t implicit return any longer.  You need a set of brackets and a return due to your const.

Comment: Better form of destructuring is in the props param itself: export const Position = ({matches, mean, price}) => ( ... );

Comment: it works, but there one caveats: now all items are printed on the field, BEFORE the click. Is there a way to print them ONLY after `toggleFullScreen()`?

Comment: I don't think that works @MattG he seems to be executing some function to get the data

Comment: hum..how so? sorry I'm new to React.

Comment: Ah yeah, phone posting and didn’t see the function call.  I would probably refactor that out though imo.  Just call the function in the parent and pass the props down.  Yes I agree that some form of state should solve his other problem though.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why `toggleFullScreen` is at the parent component, this could be internal.. i think but the gist is, you have a state that holds a boolean value of whether or not the component is at full screen, `if it is true then display data; if not then do not`

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 I've edited in some state and toogle func, if it helps

Comment: On your `Field` component, you need to pass the `fullscreen` prop as well to the `Position` component. e.g., `fullScreen={this.state.fullScreen}`. Back on `Position`, have some condition statements when you are rendering. e.g., `{props.fullScreen && <p>Name: {props.children}</p>}`

Comment: Can you complete the answer with that edit? +1 for sure

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 thanks a lot. is your condition example a fragment? or do I just have to set it before `return`?

Comment: I'm just confused as to where you mean by "back on Position". Inside the component, or before rendering it in Field?

Comment: you can use my latest code snippet example and copy paste it on my 1st snippet particularly inside of the `div` (as its child)